# Android browser shows php hidden field data?

Tags: php, android

I use hidden fields to pass data with a php form.  For windows browser, I don't have any problem.  With Android browser, the hidden fields will be visible and cause some problems.  How to modify my codes?

Thanks!

Roger

Comment: If you want advice on how to modify your code, you'll need to post your code :)

Comment: hidden with php, or something like js ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277703/hidden-fields-in-ie-are-considered-disabled and if not that one, may be this one: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/0Xbapb8KzZA (it's difficult to say without seeing the code)